# How do I get rid of this stupid thing on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

There's a block that gets rid of the text and replaces it with the thing I typed I just want the normal text editor how do I fixed this.

[image: There's a block that gets rid of the text and replaces it with the thing I typed I just want the normal text editor how do I fixed this]

Comment: Please press the `Insert` key again

Comment: As instructed in [ask], write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title. For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Answer (score 1):

Please press the `Insert` key again.

[Wikipedia: Insert key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key)

The Insert key Insert (often abbreviated Ins) is a key commonly found on computer keyboards.

It is primarily used to switch between the two text-entering modes on a personal computer (PC) or word processor.

- **overtype mode**, in which the cursor, when typing, overwrites any text that is present in the current location; and
- **insert mode**, where the cursor inserts a character at its current position, forcing all characters past it one position further.